# sub directory generated when i open my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, cloudflare

i have a web site he work normaly when i added my website to cloudflare to get free ssl certificate  the css not working.. after i checking i see a redirecting appending 5 random characters as a prefix to the subdirectory on this link https://afterlife.ovh/assets/css/templatemo-574-mexant.css
i don't have any htacces on my website files
website link : https://afterlife.ovh
help me please and thanks

i'm tried to remove cloudflare he work normly